# How can I exclude/delete flavour specific asset files through Gradle?

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

In my React Native app, I have two flavours. Each flavour has some image and video assets that are only used in that flavour.

To reduce the size of the APK, I would like to exclude unnecessary assets prior to, or during build time.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I did try using aaptOptions, along the lines of the below, but this never worked for me:

```
aaptOptions {
        '/folder:*.jpg:*.png'
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!/"+projectName+":*.mp4:"
}
```

I previously had the following task at the bottom of my build.gradle file:

```
task deleteOtherFlavourAssets(type: Delete) {
    description = 'Deleting non $projectName assets'
    delete fileTree("src").matching {
        exclude "**/app_assets_$projectName**"
        include "**/app_assets_**"
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn deleteOtherFlavourAssets
```

This did the job for a while, however it stopped working a few months ago. I've not been able to get it working again.

I should mention that when running the above task as a copy (instead of delete), the right files are duplicated into this directory.

```
task otherFlavourAssets(type: Copy) {
    description = 'Copying non $projectName assets to temp directory'
    copy {
        from fileTree("src").matching {
            exclude "**/app_assets_$projectName**"
            include "**/app_assets_**"
        }
        into 'tempAssetStore'
    }
}
```

There are no other relevant custom tasks. So it is very possible that a subsequent React Native build task is copying/merging the superfluous assets back in, or perhaps it's a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Gradle changed in this context or whether it could be a problem at all, but your filter patterns look a little weird to me. `**` is normally used to describe zero or more directory levels and I never saw patterns that use `**` in combination with a directory name. Could you try the patterns below instead?

```
task deleteOtherFlavourAssets(type: Delete) {
    description = 'Deleting non $projectName assets'
    delete fileTree("src").matching {
        exclude "**/app_assets_$projectName*/**"
        include "**/app_assets_*/**"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe that to be the problem. Having previously tried that filter pattern and running it again just now, the APK still contained two sets of images and videos. Although, the paths to some of the files concerned are seven levels deep, either variation of the pattern picks up the right files when running this task as a copy.